# Difference between XMLDoc() and ActiveXObject()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to re-write the below VB code to Javascript -

```
sub UpdateDisplay()     
    on Error resume next
    Dim objXMLDoc
    Set objXMLDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
    objXMLDoc.async = false
    objXMLDoc.load("<%=StatsURL%>")

    If (objXMLDoc.xml ="") Then 
       'alert("error")
    Else
        document.body.innerHTML=objXMLDoc.xml   

    End If
end sub

sub StartTimer()
    setInterval "UpdateDisplay",5000
end sub
```

I have come up with the below, but for some reason it's not displaying anything...

```
function updateDisplay(){
    var objDom = new XMLDoc();
    objDom.async = false;
    objDom.loadXML("<%=StatsURL%>");

    if (objDom.xml == ""){
        alert(e);
    } else{
        document.body.innerHTML = objDom.xml;
    }           
}

function startTimer(){
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){updateDisplay()},5000);
}
```

And this is being called in -

```
<body onload="Javascript:startTimer();">
```

Please note that "StatsURL" is a variable from another piece of code.

Upon looking online I found - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms764708(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms764708%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) however it shows a different way to instantiate XML DOM Doc in Javascript.

What's the difference between instantiating to a XMLDoc() compared to instantiating `var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");? I'm just trying to understand why the code I wrote didn't work.

Any constructive assistance would be great - thanks! :)

Comment: A small point I'll make is that XMLDoc is available in javascript to any browser. While AxtiveXObject is only available in IE. So, the major difference is that one will work anywhere, while the other is limited to IE. Seems like a clear choice to me!